# iPhone - Comparing a nil NSString with another valued NSString returns NSOrderedSame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, compare, equals

I'm testing a string with an other, and I notice that if the first string is nil, the return value equals NSOrderedSame (valued to 0).

`if([oneString compare:otherString] == NSOrderedSame)` returns YES if oneString is nil.

So I should test
`if(oneString != nil && [oneString compare:otherString] == NSOrderedSame)`

I guess I should also test otherString in the condition, and make a special case if I want that `[nil compare:nil]` returns `NSOrderedSame`.

Is there a more convenient way to compare string without having to do such tests and to really test if both strings are the same ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try

```
[someString isEqualToString:@"someOtherString"];
```

Or for case insensitive:

```
[[someString lowerCaseString] isEqualToString:[otherString lowerCaseString]];
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use the approach @seretur suggests unless you are worried about case. In that case, I'd use `caseInsensitiveCompare:` which is similar to the `compare:` method you are currently using.

You can also simplify that if statement like so:

```
if (oneString && [oneString caseInsensitiveCompare:otherString] == NSOrderedSame) { ...
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html), the string must not be nil. If it is, it can result in quirky behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolute legal to send something to nitl. But by definition it will always return nil. and nil itself [actually is 0](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/doing-things-in-cocoa-with.html).

If we [now look at `NSComparisonResult`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW83), `NSOrderedSame` is 0 too.

```
enum {
   NSOrderedAscending = -1,
   NSOrderedSame,
   NSOrderedDescending
};
typedef NSInteger NSComparisonResult;
```